# Ruby On Rails - In a form_for step how can I save the results of a database query into the f database in the form form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Relatively new to Ruby and have a potentially simple query.

Background
I have 3 models Listing, Category and Pricing. A Listing will have a Category, a Category will have many Pricings. Pricing is only related to Listing through the single Category selected. When a user creates a new Listing , they select a Category that Category will have 3 options for Pricing. User then selects the Pricing best appropriate for their needs.

Question
I am using a form_for to create a new listing. In one of the steps I need to query the database and identify the Pricing options available based on the Category selected and once the user selects an option then I save that option to my database driven of the form_for

My form_for structure

```
  <%= form_for @listing, html: {class: "steps-content m-l-100 m-r-100"} do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'step', @step %>
    <%= render 'step1', f: f %>
    <%= render 'step2', f: f %>
    <%= render 'step3', f: f %>
    <%= render 'step4', f: f %>
    <%= render 'step5', f: f %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

My step 2 of the model has my query to the database where i identify the Pricings for the Category

```
<div class="step-content <%= 'is-active' if @step == 2 %>">
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">    
      <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <% @listing_category_pricings.each do |data| %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag "listing_category_pricings[pricing_ids][]", nil %>
          <div class="tile is-parent">
            <article class="tile is-child box">
            <div class="subtitle"><%= "#{data.overview}" %></div>
            <div class="content"><%= "Deposit payable: £#{data.price}" %></div>
            <div class="content"><%= "Time to complete: #{pluralize(data.complete_by_date, 'Day')}" %></div>
            <tr valign="bottom"><div class="content"><%= "#{data.description}" %></div></tr>
            <tr valign="bottom"><div class="content"><%= "#{data.id}" %></div></tr>
            <%= f.check_box {***HOW DO I SAVE THE id IN THE PRICINGS MODEL INTO MY LISTINGS MODEL ??????***} %>
          </article>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I save the `id` from the `@listing_category_pricings` query into my `Listing` table. We would typically use `<%= f.checkbox :id %>` but the id that would be saved is the id from the `Listing` model and not the `Pricing` model.

Comment: In your listing model, do you have a database column where you can save the pricing id? If i'm understanding you correctly, you want to save the Pricing Id in the Listing model?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes this is correct. In my Listing model I want to save the pricing id selected by the user. I have pricing id in my Listing model

Comment: In that case, have a hidden field which saves the pricing id to the listing model, but conditionally: only if the check box is ticked ---> and you can do this by adding a vitrtual attribute (google this) to the listing model. If the check box is ticked, then save the id. If it is not ticked, then don't save the id (or otherwise handle that situation). (Having said that, I don't like your design: perhaps consider using a join table which joins the listing with the pricing id that is chosen. I don't like saving the pricing ID in the listing model - but that's just me.).